# Laravel 4: how can I understand how it all works?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 3 in one project and it's been a joy. I have also looked at the source code several times to see how some things work behind the scenes.

But now in Laravel 4, I don't know where to begin or how to understand it all. Where can I learn all the behind the scenes of Laravel 4?

Case in point: I wanted to find out if the `DB::insert()` returns the id of inserted row. So I started searching.
1. I found the Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade class that "encapsulates" DB.
2. The resolveFacadeInstance function is called and then I tried to print these arrays, but my computer hangs :-/. And I'm sure this would lead to many more classes that I wouldn't understand.

Is there a way I could try to learn the inner workings of Laravel 4? Maybe stack traces?

Comment: MIght help in the near future: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel

Answer (score 15):

The facade class is just a filter class to allow you to call methods as if they were static.
For the facade mappings go here: http://laravel.com/docs/facades#facade-class-reference

The starting point to fully understand laravel's inner-workings should begin at:

```
/public/index.php
```

You can follow the logic of the program, noticing that requires start.php, which loads an instance of the "Application" which is found here:

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
```

Comment: Hmmm, it's not much but it's a start :)

Answer (score 4):

[This Tuts+ video](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/when-they-say-laravel-shouldnt-use-static-methods/) shows a couple of ways of finding out what class is actually doing the work.

E.g.:

```
$root = get_class(DB::getFacadeRoot());
var_dump($root);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the early docs for Laravel 4 here : http://four.laravel.com/ – that should give you a good starting point

Comment: That are the docs of how to use Laravel, not the docs about the inner workings.

Answer (score 1):

The actual Laravel 4 code is well documented in the files. If you want to understand the inner workings then open up the source code files and read the notes. For example I looked up the DB::insert() code in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php.

```
/**
 * Run an insert statement against the database.
 *
 * @param  string  $query
 * @param  array   $bindings
 * @return bool
 */
public function insert($query, $bindings = array())
{
    return $this->statement($query, $bindings);
}
```

Ok, so this is calling the statement function so I search for function statement in the same code / class:

```
/**
 * Execute an SQL statement and return the boolean result.
 *
 * @param  string  $query
 * @param  array   $bindings
 * @return bool
 */
public function statement($query, $bindings = array())
{
    return $this->run($query, $bindings, function($me, $query, $bindings)
    {
        if ($me->pretending()) return true;

        $bindings = $me->prepareBindings($bindings);

        return $me->getPdo()->prepare($query)->execute($bindings);
    });
}
```

We can now see that this returns the boolean result based on the comments above the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you come from Laravel 3 [this article](http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-4-illuminating-your-laravel-3-applications) is for you. After that you should read the [other tutorials](http://jasonlewis.me/laravel-tutorials) of that series.

Author's note:

> *This article should outline some of the more important changes to Laravel between versions 3 and the upcoming version 4. Bear in mind
>   this isn’t all of the changes. As the release of Laravel 4 gets closer
>   I’ll keep this article up to date. If you’re having any problems with
>   Laravel 4 please jump on to [#laravel](http://laravel.com/irc) on Freenode. At this time we’d
>   like to ask people not to post help topics on the forums.*