# Laravel 4 class loading and facades

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to know how Laravel does class loading via Facades.

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348858/1365918) that said that the `DB` alias/facade class loaded the code

here `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php`

I tried following the advice given in the answer and following what the code does from index.php but could not understand how the `DB` Facade loaded the `Connection` class.

I also got confused some more, because the answer had said that the `Connection` class is loaded, but that class has no `connection` method. Yet the documentation says and I have been able to use the connection method like,

`DB::connection('my-connection-name');` [here's the link to the docs for this](http://four.laravel.com/docs/database#accessing-connections)

I want to know where this is all mapped and how does the loading happen. I am guessing that composer has automated the mapping, but where is it actually happening when my application boots?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use the static DB call Laravel use the mechanism provided by the Facade class in [Illuminate\Support\Facade](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Facades/Facade.php). The magic method __callStatic is called and retrieved the "original" class which is provided by the [DB facade](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Facades/DB.php) (here db).

The line 54 in Facade.php show that it use the $app variable (which is static and provided in  Illuminate\Foundation start.php file) to get the object registered as DB in the App container.

```
return static::$resolvedInstance[$name] = static::$app[$name];
```

$app['db'] is registered in [the database service provider](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/DatabaseServiceProvider.php).

Ah, and you are able to use DB and not Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB because an alias is created in app config file.

I hope this will help you :)